# Rails 4: Collection_Select does not save state after failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I have a collection select method as shown:

```
<%= fields_for :deal_venue do |dv| %>
  <div class = "field form-textarea clearfix">
    <%= dv.label "Select Venues" %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:venues, :id, @all_venues, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, :prompt => true}) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is working fine, however, after selecting all the multiple objects, if a user fails any validation when submitting the form and the form reloads, it loses all the values previously clicked by the user.

The user then has to re-select everything. So, I was wondering if there is a way to help save the instance. I looked around and did not come across any solutions.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edited**
The method calling this form is as follows:

```
def create
    @deal = Merchant.find(merchant_id).deals.new(deal_params)

    # Get all venue locations from this merchant
    @locations = Venue.pluck(:neighbourhood)
    # For drop down form
    @all_venues = MerchantService.get_all_venues(merchant_id)

    if @deal.save
      flash[:success] = "Deal successfully created!"
      redirect_to @deal
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed to create deal!"
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: You will need to pass through the parameters that you had selected to the view again when you are redirected in some way. Can you post the code for the action method please?

Comment: If you were using `dv.collection_select` it probably would.

Comment: @AdrianMann I posted the method in the controller. Thanks!

Comment: @sevenseacat i tried putting dv.collection_select but this error is throw: wrong number of arguments (7 for 4..6)

Comment: @user5296896, I think you have on too many ids, remove one if the `:id`'s.